# SFTP remove permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, net-sftp

I'm using [SFTP](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-sftp) client for fetching files froma SFTP server. I'm able to successfully read the file and store it, but I'm unsable to delete it from SFTP server after I'm done saving it.

**CODE**

```
require 'net/sftp'

class Sftp
  def self.save
    Net::SFTP.start(somehost, ****, password: ****) do |sftp|
      sftp.dir.foreach("/files") do |entry|
        next unless entry.file?

        file_name = entry.name
        source_file = "/files/#{file_name}"
        destination_file = "tmp/#{file_name}"

        sftp.download!(source_file, destination_file)

        df = File.open(destination_file, "r")
        file_data = df.read

        # Some logic to utilise read file info. in variable "file_data"

        File.delete(df) # deleted from tmp
        sftp.remove!(source_file) # deleted from sftp server
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When the line `sftp.remove!(source_file)` is executed, I get error like:

> "Net::SFTP::StatusException (3, \"permission denied\")"

Permission for **files** directory

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root    4096 Dec 22 10:54 files
```

Permission for files inside the **files** directory:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Dec 22 10:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   4096 Dec 18 15:29 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 749199 Dec 18 14:39 a.pdf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   7945 Dec 18 15:41 b.pdf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   7945 Dec 22 10:54 c.pdf
```

**EDIT**

I replaced the following line of code

```
sftp.remove!(source_file)
```

with

```
sftp.send(:exec, "sudo rm /var/sftp/#{source_file}")
```

Now, the removal works, but only for the first file. Then the loop exits without any error.

What may be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you are logging in to the remote host as a user other than root. Is this correct?

Your problem is that root is the owner of those files on the remote host, and as a user other than root you are not authorized to delete them.

If you are in control of the remote files, you might want to save them by a user other than root -- one whom you can log in as to delete them but one whom others cannot, assuming you don't want others to be able to delete files.

If you log in to that server as root, you should be able to delete the files.

Regarding this code:

```
df = File.open(destination_file, "r")
file_data = df.read
File.delete(df) # deleted from tmp
```

This is an overly complicated way to accomplish deleting the file. You are reading the file's data into `file_data` but not doing anything with it. Also, there is no need to open a file to delete it -- you can call `File.delete` on a filespec rather than a File object.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I'm logging in with different user. Secondly, I do use `file_data`, but I didn't post that code as it was not relevant to the context, my focus is to delete file from SFTP server.

Comment: My main intention is to delete the file from SFTP server so that I don't read it again.

Comment: By the way, Ruby provides `File.read` and `File.readlines` methods that eliminate the need to explicitly open the file.

Comment: @Abhi You did not address my suggestions. Do you have any questions about them?

Comment: I tried to set the permission of the files with the local user instead of **root**, but it didn't work. Also, I found this post bit helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/1619146/2968762. But, I had to use `sftp.send(:exec, "rm full_path_to_#{source_file}")`, because **exec** a private method. And for some unknown reason after removing the first file, due to the above code, the loop breaks out without error. I'm clueless.

Comment: It would be helpful at this point for you to put your code up where we could see it. Using a gist (a single fragment of code or text, often containing the contents of a file) on Github is great for this; it color codes your code, and keeps history. If you don't have a Github id, I recommend registering for one, and then go to gist.github.com and adding a gist.

Comment: If you are going to execute code on that server, I recommend using `ssh`, as that's one of its intended purposes (unlike sftp). Normally, `ssh` and `sftp` will normally put you in the home directory of the user with which you've logged in. You don't really even need a library if your OS has `ssh` and `sftp` commands; you can build and execute an external command such as ` ``ssh user@host rm #{filespec_to_delete}`` `; though in general using a Ruby library is better when possible.

Comment: Regarding my comment about a gist, posting the code here on Stack Overflow is better when possible. I mention a gist in case it's a _lot_ of code.